# Where em lista de strings não funciona Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, angular, typescript

Não estou conseguindo retornar os documentos de uma coleção onde esse documento possui um campo chamado tags que é uma lista de strings com o ID da tag.

Abaixo segue o código do que estou tentando fazer:

```
document = this.afs.collection('todos',
    ref => ref.where(tags, '==', 'ASOEOIN35O34N5O'));
```

Os campos do documento são:

**Document (todos):**

```
title: 'TITULO',
notes: 'NOTAS',
completed: true,
important: false,
tags: [{
 0: 'ASOEOIN35O34N5O',
 1: 'PWEPORJN2PNPGEW',
 3: 'POKAPASJPASFGGG'
}]
```

Ao realizar uma consulta com uma query, nada é retornado.

O que posso estar fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como está na [Documentação do Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays?hl=pt-br), utilizar os dados assim não permite fazer o que você quer. Eles entretanto, propoem uma alternativa para fazer com que funcione. Você pode estruturar os seus dados da seguinte forma:

```
// Estrutura do documento na colecao
{
    title: "TITLE",
    note: "NOTE",
    completed: true,
    important: true,
    tags: {
         "ASOEOIN35O34N5O": true,
         "PWEPORJN2PNPGEW": true,
         "POKAPASJPASFGGG": true
    }
}
```

Perceba que nesse caso, ao invés de termos um array, temos um objeto, onde os atributos dele são as tags que você deseja usar. Depois basta fazer a query, que pelo que vi do seu código, se tornaria:

```
this.afs.collection('todos')
    .where('tags.ASOEOIN35O34N5O', '==', true)
    .get()
    .then(docs => docs.forEach(doc => console.log(doc.data()))
```